If a post seeks general advice on dealing with a perceived problem in a community, should we always migrate it into that community's meta?
I asked a general question here a few days ago about strategies for curtailing overly zealous deleting. I think it received about 8 upvotes here. A resourceful user deduced which site I was experiencing problems with (Space Exploration) and this community decided to migrate the question to that site. I do not doubt that this decision was made properly, in accordance with how things are done on SE Meta.
I and another user provided answers to the question after it was migrated, but unfortunately, a moderator over on Space Exploration deleted both answers. I was also suspended for seven days at the same time that my answer was deleted.
I believe that in general, Space Exploration is a pretty good community. I also believe that if you see something, you should say something - being at all times respectful of other's opinions, even when you disagree with them. I think the topic of when trusted users should vote-to-delete does need to be more actively discussed to improve the overall health of that site.
If users on other sites experience similar concerns, they may be able to learn something useful from that now-migrated question, its answers, and the comments. But, because the question was migrated and then its answers were deleted, I'm afraid that this information has been essentially hidden from the wider community.
So, my question to the SE Meta community is...

When a post asks for general advice on how to deal with a perceived problem within a community, is it always the best policy to investigate and identify the specific community at issue and then migrate the post into that community?

I agree that it's probably a good idea most of the time. My question is really about whether sometimes, in specific cases, it might be of more benefit to all Stack Exchange communities (and protect advice seekers) to not migrate the post.

I've trimmed away the references to the content that got you suspended on Space Exploration. This isn't the place to discuss the circumstances around your suspension. We should focus on your concerns about migration. If you feel like your suspension was in error/should be overturned/you have more to add to it, you should respond to the moderator message you received alongside your suspension, or, use the Contact Us form to reach SE staff.

I'm good with that. I just felt that it provided relevant context. Thanks for the link!

We could just delete the post I suppose. Would that have been a better experience for you or would you have found that just as frustrating. The fundamental problem is that the question isn't appropriate here so that leaves us with migration or deletion ad our two options.

While I will address the specific migration question, I wanted to start by talking about why many questions are better served on child metas than main meta. I'll also note that only mods/staff can migrate questions to child metas, so most of the time questions are likely to be closed as "Relates to only one specific network site" rather than migrated.
In general I recommend that users keep questions about experiences on a specific site on that site's meta - or at least start there. It's far better for a community to say "We discussed this on our meta and couldn't come up with a good solution for us - what do other communities on SE do?", than for a user to start the discussion here on MSE first.
There are many reasons for this, there are a few that I see repeatedly, which I'll discuss below. I want to emphasize, I'm stating these things as examples that have happened in the past. I do not intend to imply that they relate to your question specifically but I need to mention them if this explanation is going to be complete.

Applicability - While there are often benefits to discussions about policy across the network, a practice that works on some sites won't always align with the culture or subject matter of every site. As such, the recommendation for how to handle a situation may not be useful.
I ran into this issue frequently when I was a moderator on Interpersonal Skills. We often had to use quite different policy than other sites due to the more subjective nature of that site's scope.
Autonomy - Similar to the above, other than what's built into the platform and company-instilled policy, sites have a lot of flexibility in deciding how to manage themselves. Getting a "best practice" here on MSE doesn't mean the specific site has to accept or adopt that practice. As such, it's frequently better to start the discussion locally to see if there already is a practice in place, even if it's only tacitly implied.
Specificity - Whenever the discussion revolves around the behavior of a very small group of users - especially if it's only one user - this is generally something that, in particular, needs local discussion as the MSE community can not determine whether or not the assessment of the situation is an accurate one. As such, it's generally best to broach the situation on the child meta along with specific examples and see if the community agrees the issue exists.
Seeking override of local decisions - I admit, this one's a bit touchy - but the simple truth is that many users come to MSE to draw attention to issues they feel are not being adequately handled on a specific site, in the hopes of having the broader meta community "overrule" decisions a site/ moderators have made. I list this last as the prior three examples explain why this is a poor tactic and, if discovered, often leads to a negative MSE reception.

Instead, the best option is to reach out to the Community Management team directly through the contact link using the "other" option.



Again, I have no idea what led you to asking the question here but I hope these explanations help you see why it's better to start on the child meta in most cases rather than MSE.
As such, yes - these questions are often - though not always - better off migrated to the child meta or otherwise closed on MSE unless they can be edited to make it clear that it's a question that benefits from a broader discussion (e.g. identifying that it's an issue seen on many sites rather than one).
Unfortunately, determining which is the best option in any specific case can be somewhat subjective and the final action will depend on who's looking at the post.
When I was a CM, I tended to migrate questions that were obviously better suited to a child meta because it was easier than closing and making the asker repost the question. That said, it would depend on whether the question followed the guidance that migrations should only be used for good questions. I would also generally check to ensure that the "override" example wasn't the case. If it was, I would often contact the site mods to make them aware of the MSE discussion and ask if they wanted it migrated or not.
Most users can't migrate, so their choices are to flag and ask the mods to migrate, vote to close the question with the more general "Relates to only one specific network site" or go with a duplicate closure if there's a canonical discussion that seems appropriate. Of course, if they feel it is appropriate for broader discussion on MSE, they have the option to answer or edit the question to make it a better fit for MSE.

This post provides a lot of food for thought. My takeaway is that if the answers to an MSE question will be generally applicable and likely to cross-pollinate potentially good solutions or policies from one site's experience to others - without being proscriptive about which particular solutions or policies the autonomous sites should adopt - then the question would be appropriate for MSE. Did I come close to where your head is at on this?
